# How Azure Function using PowerShell can issue Invoke-Command to another computer?

Tags: powershell, azure-functions

I am trying to do something straightforward, use PowerShell Invoke-Command from an Azure Function. The destination machine is in my Azure subscription and in the same virtual network. The code below fails with the error below.

A difficulty is that Azure Functions are "serverless" so when I try various solutions, such as setting the local TrustedHosts file, it fails because there is no such file.

I want to use the simplest method that is reasonably secure. I tried various other authentication schemes with no luck.

```
using namespace System.Net

# Input bindings are passed in via param block.
param($Request, $TriggerMetadata)

$adminName = 'chuck-admin'
$adminPassword = 'XXXXXXX'
$secPassword = ConvertTo-SecureString $adminPassword -AsPlainText -Force
$vmCreds = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ($adminName, $secPassword)

$vmReturn = Invoke-Command  -ComputerName chuck-vm-3    -Credential $vmCreds  -ScriptBlock{whoami}

Push-OutputBinding -Name Response -Value ([HttpResponseContext]@{
    StatusCode = [HttpStatusCode]::OK
    Body = $vmReturn
})
```

System.Management.Automation.Remoting.PSRemotingTransportException: 
    Connecting to remote server chuck-vm-3 failed with the following error message : 
    The WinRM client cannot process the request. If the authentication scheme is different from Kerberos, or if the client computer is not joined to a domain, then HTTPS transport must be used or the destination machine must be added to the TrustedHosts configuration setting.
    Use winrm.cmd to configure TrustedHosts. Note that computers in the TrustedHosts list might not be authenticated.
    You can get more information about that by running the following command: winrm help config. For more information, see the about_Remote_Troubleshooting Help topic.

Comment: Not sure if you are checking the same, but there is a [official doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-hybrid-powershell) that covers this. Also, could you perhaps try saving the TrustedHosts file in blob storage, fetch it from there and store it in the appropriate place on each run?

Comment: Update... I was able to get remote VM control working, from a plain VM source to a plain VM target. The solution was several WinRM settings like this:

set-item -force WSMan:\localhost\client\TrustedHosts 10.10.0.17
set-item -force WSMan:\localhost\client\AllowUnencrypted $true

But that code does not work within an Azure Function because WinRM is not installed there. 

Thank you for that article link. I have seen it. It addresses remote control of an on-prem machine, which is not what I am doing. I am going Azure to Azure. But maybe something in there will help.

Comment: Apart from the hybrid connection piece, I believe the rest of the article should be of help. Please share any findings that could help others if any.

Comment: I am working through it now. It appears to say "pretend your native Azure VM is outside of Azure (on prem)" which seem convoluted, but I will move forward with it and post the results.